# Beppo Levi's theorem

Tags: integration, measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $f_n$ is a sequence of integrable functions and $\sup_n\int f_n d\mu<\infty$. I need to show that, if $f_n\uparrow f$, then $f$ is integrable and $\int f_nd\mu \rightarrow \int fd\mu$. This is claimed to be named as "Beppo Levi's theorem".

It is not stated that $f_n$ are non-negative or non-negative a.e., so it is clearly not the same assumptions of Monotone convergence theorem. I have no clue how to show the convergence of the integral in case of the above assumptions, and not the non-negativeness assumption.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Define
$$g_n=f_{n}-f_1$$

Then $g_n$ is an increasing sequence of non-negative integrable functions, and $g_n\to g:=f-f_1$, thus by monotone convergence theorem
$$\int g_n d\mu\to\int g d\mu$$

Thus the result follows.

Comment: So why $f$ is integrable? I think we will need this to apply the linearity of integral to remove integral of $f_1$ from both sides.

Comment: Exactly. We have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_n d\mu=\int f-f_1+f_1d\mu=\int f d\mu$$

Comment: I do not get this. How did you add $f_1$ to $g_n$ and $g$. And how does this show that $f$ is integrable?

Comment: The monotone convergence theorem says $\int g_n\to\int g$, and we know that $\sup_n\int g_n<\infty$ since $\sup_n\int f_n<\infty$ by assumption, thus $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int g_n$ must be finite, which means $g$ is integrable, so $f$ is also integrable.