# Beppo Levi's theorem, is this assertion correct?

Tags: lebesgue-integral

My notes report the following assertion for the theorem:

**Beppo Levi's Theorem:** Let $E$ be a measurable set and $\{ f_n(x)\}$ a sequence of integrable functions on E, such that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f_n(x) = f(x)$ (pointwise convergence) almost everywhere on E, and $f_n(x)\leq f(x)$. Then $f(x)$ is integrable on E and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \int\limits_E f_n(x) = \int\limits_E f(x)$

Is this correct? Cause my book reports multiple versions of the theorem, but not this one.

Comment: What does punctual convergence mean?

Comment: Pointwise, my bad, translation error. Let me correct it

Comment: It should be only $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f_n(x) = f(x)$ without "for every $n$" because $n$ is already in the limit sign.

Comment: I don't know why, but my notes report both. I'll take your tip anyway!

Comment: As is, the statement is wrong, because $E=\mathbb{R}^+$, $f_n=1_{[-n,n]}$ seems to give your theorem a problem.

Comment: OK, thanks for reporting that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First this theorem is wrong**

Consider $E = \mathbb R$, $f=0$ and $f_n = -\chi_{[n,n+1]}$. Where $\chi_{[n,n+1]}$ is the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) of the interval $[n,n+1]$.

They satisfy the hypothesis, but the conclusion doesn't hold as

$$ -1 = \int_{\mathbb R} f_n \neq \int_{\mathbb R} f = 0$$
while $(f_n)$ converges pointwise to the always vanishing function $f$.

**Second this would more related to dominated convergence theorem**

See [Dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) if the hypothesis would be correctly set.

Answer (score 2):

The theorem is usually known as the [monotone convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Beppo_Levi's_monotone_convergence_theorem_for_Lebesgue_integral) and comes with an extra requirement that 
$$
f_1(x)\le f_2(x)\le\dots \le f(x)
$$
for almost every $x$. Other than this the other parts of your statement is correct.

Comment: My notes report that the classical statement requires that $f_1(x) < f_2(x) < \dots < f_n(x) < \dots$ but it can be proved not to be necessary... Isn't that right?

Comment: That’s not the monotone convergence theorem. There is no assumption on the sequence $f_n$.

Comment: @Bafforasta Then you'd need extra assumptions. As it is now the statement is not true.

Comment: @Mindlack I know the statement in the OP is not the MCT that's why I said that it missed one assumption, i.e. monotonicity. The reason being the name Beppo Levi is associated with the MCT so I made the link.

Comment: @BigbearZzz I just found this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1177788/beppo-levis-theorem this looks pretty similar

Comment: @Bafforasta See the assumption $f_n\uparrow f$, that's the monotonicity that I wrote in my post.

Comment: OK, thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Bafforasta I think this should conclude the question. Just as I suggested (or even the post you linked to), you'd need monotonicity assumption for the theorem to be true. The other answer gave a counterexample saying that your statement  without any modification is false. If you don't want monotonicity, then you'd need the Dominated convergence theorem which assumes that all $|f_n|$ are bounded by an integrable function.